# $.seralize() to recognize form elements changes within jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using  `$('#myForm').seralize()` to pass arguments to a server-side component via `$.ajax()` however, when I include any form elements into a div that jqueryui dialog uses, the `$('#myForm').seralize()` does not recognize any form element changes within that div.

Please see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vXLve/4/) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `$('#dialog').dialog()` moves `#dialog` out of the `#myform` `<div>` by cloning it entirely to another location (the bottom of the page, I believe).

You can find the inputs in the dialog by using:

```
$('#dialog :input').serialize();
```

Perhaps you could split up the two sets and send them back to the server together:

```
...
data: { 
    common: $('#myForm').serialize(),
    dialog: $('#dialog :input').serialize();
},
...
```

Or maybe you can just combine them, like so:

```
...
data: $('#myForm').serialize() + '&' + $('#dialog :input').serialize(),
...
```

An updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/consultcory/vXLve/8/).

Comment: Thanks! I went with your second suggestion `data: $('#myForm').serialize() + '&' + $('#dialog :input').serialize(),`

Comment: @isurfbecause: Just be careful about possible duplicate keys. You might be better off converting the two serialized strings into objects, and then extending one with the other using `jQuery.extend()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use jQuery UI dialog, it actually wrap your $('#myForm') again and move it directly under the  level.

You can do "inspect element" via firebug/chrome devtool on your dialog, and you will found that the dialog element does not belongs in the form element anymore, therefore the checkbox data is missing.

You can bind a callback or make another form and get seralized string like this;

```
$('#form_1').serialize() + '&' + $('#form_2').serialize();
```

hope it helps, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI Dialogs get placed either at the beginning or end (i forget which) of the body tag, meaning those elements are no longer part of the form. If you are using HTML5, you can fix that by giving those inputs a new attribute: `form="myForm"`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vXLve/7/

Comment: This worked great in Chrome but not in IE9. This was something I did not know. Thanks!